# MySQL PHP Compare two tables and replace values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a requirement to look at two tables and based on the column "id" where matching I need to replace the data in table "data" with what is in table "master data"

Here is table "data"

```
id      Required GPA
ZZZWD   2.2
EDFRD   4.0
DCFRE   
EDFRG   3.0
```

Here is table "master data"

```
id      Required GPA
ZZZWD   2.2
EDFRD   3.5
DCFRE   2.1
EDFRG   4.4
```

What is the most efficent way to do this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work out for you:

```
UPDATE `data`, `master_data`
SET `data`.required_GPA = `master_data`.required_GPA
WHERE `data`.id <> `master_data`.id
AND (`data`.required_GPA is null OR `data`.required_GPA = '')
```